# Ext Js combobox value after onchange is value instead of label

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid

Just getting frustrated by something that should be an easy fix, but I'm too simple minded to see it :)

I'm having a grid where 1 column is a combobox. The thing works just fine and the correct value is beeing sent through my ajax request, but after I edited the grid row, the combobox disappread and the value that comes into place is not the label, but the value.

```
editor: new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
            typeAhead: true,
            lazyRender: true,
            store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                fields: ['contact', 'contactLabel'],
                data: [
                    [1,'Jan'],
                    [2,'Jeroen'],
                    [3,'Mattijs'],
                    [4,'Sven'],
                    [5,'Thomas'],
                    [6,'Yoran']
                ]
            }),
            valueField: 'contact',
            displayField: 'contactLabel',
            hiddenName: 'contact'
        })
```

So what happens is that when I change the combobox to i.e.. "Thomas", the value of the cell becomes "5", instead of "Thomas". I thought that defining value/display fields would make a difference, but it does not.

Anyone that knows the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I got you right. If so you will need a renderer for that. I guess the example below the code snipped should show you if you are meaning such a case.

```
// the renderer. You should define it within a namespace
var comboBoxRenderer = function(combo) {
  return function(value) {
    var idx = combo.store.find(combo.valueField, value);
    var rec = combo.store.getAt(idx);
    return (rec === null ? '' : rec.get(combo.displayField) );
  };
}

// the edit combo
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
  store: store,
  valueField: "value",
  displayField: "text"
});
```

See this full working example for both (cellEditing + rowEditing) **[JSFiddle ()](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/Sj8zM/16/)**

Here's the complete code

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone', 'id'],
    data:{'items':[
        {"name":"Lisa", "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-111-1224","id": 0},
        {"name":"Bart", "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1234","id": 1},
        {"name":"Homer", "email":"home@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1244","id": 2},
        {"name":"Marge", "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254","id": 3}
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

    // the combo store
var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
  fields: [ "value", "text" ],
  data: [
    [ 0, "Option 0" ],
    [ 1, "Option 1" ],
    [ 2, "Option 2" ],
    [ 3, "Option 3" ]
  ]
});

// the renderer. You should define it within a namespace
var comboBoxRenderer = function(combo) {
  return function(value) {
    var idx = combo.store.find(combo.valueField, value);
    var rec = combo.store.getAt(idx);
    return (rec === null ? '' : rec.get(combo.displayField) );
  };
}

// the edit combo
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
  store: store,
  valueField: "value",
  displayField: "text"
});


// demogrid
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'},
        {header: 'id', dataIndex: 'id', editor: combo, renderer: comboBoxRenderer(combo)}
    ],
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: 'cell'
});
// demogrid
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'},
        {header: 'id', dataIndex: 'id', editor: combo, renderer: comboBoxRenderer(combo)}
    ],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: 'row'
});
```

**html**

```
<div id="cell"></div>
<div id="row"></div>
```

Comment: I must be missing something here. I'm getting:

TypeError: rec is undefined
return (rec === null ? '' : rec.get(combo.displayField));

I'm using the rowEditing plugin btw. Don't know if that should make any difference?

Comment: @DinandDerksen Well, no. That shouldn't make any differences. JSFiddle is currently unavailable so I am not able to provide a example with a rowEditing plugin. Try change the line `rec === null ?` to `rec ?` And note that the boxRender must know the instance of the combo used by the editior.

Comment: Thank you so much, sra!

I've got it working exactly as I want. The only thing that I had to change was that the keys in the store array had to be marked as strings, instead of integers. Somehow I got i.e. "3" when editor was activated, instead of "Option 3". Anyway ... it sends the correct value through ajax and shows the right values in the combobox before and after save. Thanks a LOT!

Comment: Keep in mind this solution only works if the entire store has been loaded from the DB.  Or, at least the record matching the ID.  For example, an `employee` combobox that points to a store with 10,000 employees (that uses paging) has a good chance of not finding the record.  I'm currently working on a better solution as our combo has many records and we can't have a load for each grid row.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data: [
    {contact: 1, contactLabel: 'Jan'},
    ...
]
```